# Problem with high reputation requirements for tag wiki edits?

Tags: support

Has something odd happened to the "tag wiki" reputation limit?  Having just ticked over 5000, I looked at my reputation page and saw that I had 50% of the rep to get moderator tools, **and 25% of the rep required to edit tag wikis**.  Mouseover says that now requires **20000** reputation, but I vaguely recall it needing **2000** when last I looked.  Has an extra zero crept into a config file anywhere?

Comment: I don't know if that's a mistake or not but I can approve edits to tag-wikis, maybe it's just a double check system... makes sense to have two sets of eyes on those anyway.

Comment: If it's 20K to make unapproved edits and everything else subject to approvals like for 1-rep users editing that kinda makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is 20k to make unapproved edits, as noted by voretaq7.

All other edits must be voted and approved.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff; is that a recent change, or am I just losing my memory?

Comment: shouldn't this be marked status-bydesign?